# Can I view raw message in iron.io webpage?

Tags: laravel-5, message-queue, iron.io, push-queue

I'm learning to use iron.io MQ push queues. I'm pushing some messages with Laravel php framework and everything works. However, just to round up my knowledge, I would like to see the raw contents of these messages. In my iron.io account I can see the total number of messages sent, but I can't find a place where to inspect individual messages and their contents. I'm wondering weather Laravel is sending some ID's or anything like that..

Answer (score 0):

Laravel is using [IronMQ's Push Queues](http://dev.iron.io/mq/reference/push_queues/) and since push queues are delivered  immediately, they don't stick around upon successful delivery. Although, you can create an [error queue](http://dev.iron.io/mq/reference/push_queues/#error_queues) to inspect messages that can't be delivered successfully.